# Microsoft Graph get AD group members with extensionattributes

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk9Ci.png) I'm trying get AD group member extensionattributes with Microsoft Graph but i can't make this work.

I need get AD attributes: givenName, surname, employeeID, mail, department, jobTitle, ExtensionAttribute4

In HTTP response i get only: givenName, surname, mail, jobTitle, department

and i have added everything necessary to AD -> AAD sync.

Any helps?

Comment: Please share the error you faced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `employeeID` should be changed to `employeeId`. And the `ExtensionAttribute4` is in `onPremisesExtensionAttributes`.

So try the following URL in your logic app:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/members?$select=givenName, surname, employeeId, mail, department, jobTitle, onPremisesExtensionAttributes
```

For more details about user properties, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).